# Google Admobs integrated in android application

Tags: java, android, admob

I have integrated [Google AdMob](https://www.google.com/admob/) in my Android application. Now my application has advertisements, but I don't approve of every ad that is displayed. I consider some ads to be vulgar or sexual -- for example, advertisements for condoms.

How can I limit the advertisements to things that I don't want to be shown in my app?

Comment: What are the vulgar, sexual ads?

Comment: adds of condom.

Comment: Editing for improved legibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via admob console like this ,select which category you want,

[image: like this]

Comment: It can take a while for the changes to take effect, give it few hours, as it needs to be synchronized across all servers.

Answer (score 0):

AdMob has controls over content:
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3150235?hl=en